# Servicestack losing session, until cache clear, after pushing bin/js files

Tags: c#, session, servicestack

ServiceStack app using Angular (but issue occurs with just /auth as well *see below)

Browsers where I definitely run into issue: Chrome, Safari

Running into an issue where user is losing session immediately after login redirect. I've tested using /auth?username&password as well, I get the session Id just fine, but going back to /auth shows me as unauthorized.

Clearing cache works to resolve the issue, as does using incognito mode.

I attempted to add versioning to CSS and JS files just in case that was the issue when pushing, but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Steps to reproduce

- Push dlls, js files
- go to staging website
- attempt to login ...success
- redirect and session gone

Any ideas on where to look/solve this issue without forcing application users to clear cache? Any ideas/direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Does the user stay on the same domain when redirecting? Are you using session cookies or a session state server? Checked your session cookie/server values/settings?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this got me looking at the cookie domains which lead to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured out the issue! This one was fun.

Setup:
We have two servicestack sites

- example.com //on staging this was SSL
- sub.example.com //on staging this was non-SSL

Here's how the problem reproduced, when testing we would....

- log into example.com at some point prior which would produce a .example.com cookie domain
- We'd push file changes to sub.example.com which would wipe cookies for this subdomain
- We'd attempt to login to sub.example.com and fail
- If I removed .example.com cookies from example.com, logging into sub.example.com would be fine

To fix, we made sub.example.com SSL as well, which fixed the issue. Longterm we'll make all the cookies wildcard and add a non-memcache provider per Mythz suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `MemoryCacheClient` then adding files to your Web App's folder will restart the ASP.NET App Domain which restarts your Web App, clearing all existing memory.

You'll need to use any other [distributed Caching Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) in order to retain your Cache and Sessions beyond App Domain restarts.